# Reset negative vote counts on migrated questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, migration

Often a question is voted down by a member of a site because the question doesn't belong on that site and the voter doesn't have enough reputation to vote to close the question.  In situations like this where the question is simply asked in the wrong forum, the vote count on the question should be reset to give the question a fair chance on the correct site when the question is migrated.

Related to:

[Separate close to move from other close reasons and reduce reputation required](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6613/feature-request-decrease-the-reputation-required-to-close-as-belongs-on-another)
[Do migrated questions migrate reputation and badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6378/do-migrated-questions-migrate-reputation-and-badges)