# Now that there is a League of Super Heroes should the number of votes required to close/move be reduced?

Tags: discussion, migration

It used to be that most questions that were off-topic got closed quickly.  That disturbed people because there were differing opinions over what constituted "programming-related".  Now a family of web sites is available to handle many of these and there is/could be less disagreement over how to handle many off-topic questions as they are simply moved, not actually closed.  This means that the conversation can still take place, albeit in a different, more appropriate forum.

Still, it takes 5 votes to close/move a question and some questions can linger and get answers in the "wrong" forum.  These get migrated, but as the communities grow answers in the correct forum are more likely to be correct.  As we've seen, though, early, up-voted answers tend to get more traction than even later, more correct answers.  That being the case, it seems better to migrate questions to the correct forum more quickly.

Should the number of votes to close be reduced from its current number, or would we just get back into close wars?

Related to this feature request:

[Separate close to move from other close reasons and reduce reputation required](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6613/separate-close-to-move-from-other-close-reasons-and-reduce-reputation-required)

Answer (score 4):

It takes 5 votes *or a moderator* to close/move a question. I think it's okay - I haven't seen a significant number of "bad" questions lingering for a long time. 5 still isn't very many votes - at least not on SO. I dare say it takes a while longer on SF/SU, but it'll gradually improve as they get more users.

Comment: A time traveler from the future: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.

Answer (score 4):

SO scaled up close votes required as the number of people who can vote to close increased. I think it makes sense to do that with SU and SF. I'd probably suggest 3 for SU, 4 for SF, 5 for SO still and it can scale up as required over time.

I don't really see any reason to increase above 5, at least not yet.

Comment: Possibly make it decide based on active users with enough reputation to cast close votes?