# OpenID logins broken for all StackExchange 1.0 sites (including meta.stackexchange)

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, openid

Apologies for not posting this on http://meta.stackexchange.com, but I can't log into that site because all OpenID logins to StackExchange 1.0 sites (including meta.stackexchange) are broken now, and have been broken for at least a few hours.

Known problem? Is there an ETA for a fix?

I can repro this on multiple OpenID providers-- looks like it's a StackExchange problem, not a provider-specific one.  It also occurs on all StackExchange 1.0 sites (including Fog Creek's own support sites for [FogBugz](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/) and [Kiln](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/)) so it's not specific to any particular StackExchange 1.0 site.  Although of course I'm posting because our company's support site http://answers.splunk.com/ is affected too.

To repro:

1. go to http://meta.stackexchange.com
2. click log in
3. click the link to log in with OpenID
4. click any openid provider (I used MyOpenID)
5. enter your openid info (e.g. username)

**Expected:** 
works

**Actual:**

Got this error message:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> Web request to 'http://[my username redacted here].myopenid.com/' failed.

Here's info that looks like the SE version info:

```
<meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100413135304-37b86aed49ad)">
```

**UPDATE:**

Linking to dupe filed on meta.stackexchange (presumably by someone with a cached login!) :
[Separate close to move from other close reasons and reduce reputation required](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6613/openid-login-is-broken-on-all-stackexchange-1-0-sites)

Comment: same here - using google as openID provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[My answer from meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6613/openid-login-is-broken-on-all-stackexchange-1-0-sites/6614#6614):

> We had a router issue in the
>   datacenter. The secondary router came
>   online almost immediately, so sites
>   were still accessible, but the web
>   servers were not able to reach
>   addresses outside the network, a
>   requirement for OpenID.
>
> Everything should be running again as
>   of about 9:27 AM Eastern -- let us
>   know if you see any more issues.
>
> We're very sorry about the downtime,
>   and the sys admins are looking in to
>   it to make sure it doesn't happen
>   again.